# SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: jquery, ajax

I apologies if this has already been answered.  I'm running this code successfully in Chrome, IE9 but in IE8 and IE7 I'm getting a "SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method " (doesn't say which property or method) line 1 character 1.  I'm stumped.  Can someone put me out of my mysery?  (Using jQuery v1.6.2.)  Thanks so much.

(To everyone who has helped me this morning, thank so much.  The snippet I posted was part of a much larger project and I tried to identify the piece that I "thought" was causing the problem.  After stripping out a mile of code, I'm now able to veryify that IE7 and IE8 are producing : SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method testkw.cfm, line 67 character 6.

This is at line 67:

```
$('.IDlookup').click(function() {                
    ID  = $(IDval).attr('value');                
    var r = "test.cfm";
    $.get(r,function(data){
        $("#Details").html(data);
    });
});
```

This is the entire template

```
<div id="Message" style="padding-left:10px;">

  <div style="margin-top:5px; margin-bottom:5px;">
    <input class="add" type="radio" id="_ID" name="lookupType" value="ID" />
    ID
    <input class="add" type="radio" id="_name" name="lookupType" value="name" />
Name</div>
  <div id="ID" class="rTypedesc" style="display:none; padding-left:5px;">
    <input type="text" id="IDval" name="IDval" value="Enter EntityID/ID" />
    <a class="IDlookup">Find &raquo;</a> </div>
  <div id="name" class="rTypedesc" style="display:none;">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" id="nameinput" name="nameinput" /></td>
        <td style="padding-left:5px;"><a class="name">Find &raquo;</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="Details"></div>
<script >
//
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});





  $("input[name$='lookupType']").click(function() {         
    var rType = $(this).val();         
    $(".rTypedesc").hide();         
    $("#"+rType).show();  
    });  

  $('.IDlookup').click(function() {              
    var ID  = $('IDval').attr('value');                  
        var r = "test.cfm?id="+ID;
        $.get(r,function(data){
        $("#Details").html(data);
        });
      });


  $('.name').click(function() {              
       var ID  = $('nameinput').attr('value');                   
        var r = "test.cfm?id="+ID;
        $.get(r,function(data){
        $("#Details").html(data);
        });
      });

     $('#IDval').click(function() {
         $(this).val();
     });

</script>
```

Comment: You are using " at Message.cfm instead of ;also $function is not reuired many..lemme post the changed code.

Comment: `$(IDval).attr('value')`: Where `IDval` is defined? Should it be `$('#IDval').attr('value')`?

Answer (score 4):

if error coming from ID  = $(IDval).attr('value');  then just place "var" behind it, as

```
var ID  = $(IDval).attr('value');
```

it will resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you copied and pasted the code above as is, you've got a stray double-quote (`"`) on the line `var MyData = Message.cfm"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 //
$.ajaxSetup ({
  // Disable caching of AJAX responses
 cache: false
});

  $(document).ready(function () {
 $('#Message').html('<p><img src="/seccomm/img/ajax-loader-2.gif" width="20"  />');
 var MyData = "Message.cfm";
 $("#Message").load(MyData);  
 });
</script>
```

EDIT : OP edited the Qn

Comment: Thx Rocket, tried your suggestion, but I'm still getting the script error in IE 7 and IE8

Comment: I have... However, I tried to represent a great deal of code with the "snippet" I posted (and it incorrectly represents what may be happening).  I'm going to edit my initial post now.

Comment: @Kerrie : Sorry to say You are confusing us. Also in your edited post the error is >> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support this property or method testkw.cfm >> but in the snippet you have provided it is "test.cfm" at 67 ..huhe

Comment: @Kerrie : What is this line for  >> ID  = $(IDval).attr('value'); did ID is initialized? also are you using it any where?

Comment: Thanks for hanging in there with me... This is definatley the line that's causing the problem.  I have a radio button that's toggling the display of a div.  ID is the value of the radio button (i'm editing my code again) ... Thank you soo much.

Comment: user1042031 I have it working... your comments were a huge help by simply making me think :-).  I'll post an explanation of my fix.